# SSH known_hosts with a dynamic IP

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-keys, tunneling, known-hosts

I have a machine behind a firewall. I connect to it remotely using a VPN tunneling with a port forward through ssh. To connect to the machine I use the external IP of the VPN and my personal and temporary assigned port. The command I use is:

```
ssh USER@VPN_IP -p PORT
```

Since `VPN_IP` and `PORT` change frequently I cannot get advantages of saving the host key in `known_host` to get rid of man man-in-the-middle attacks, but at the same time the host key is well known to me and I could provide it to ssh in order to use it for the current `VPN_IP` and `PORT` combination. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 8):

The `known_hosts` file is for providing these keys and there's no direct command line alternative (and it wouldn't be so handy, anyway). However, your goal is completely possible with the `known_hosts` file!

Read through `man sshd`'s [`ssh_known_hosts` file format](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT).

> When performing host authentication, authentication is accepted if any
>   matching line has the proper key; either one that matches exactly or,
>   if the server has presented a certificate for authentication, the key
>   of the certification authority that signed the certificate.

It is possible to use wildcards in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`):

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment. The fields are separated by spaces.
>
> Hostnames is a comma-separated list of patterns (`*` and `?` act as
>   wildcards); each pattern in turn is matched against the canonical host
>   name (when authenticating a client) or against the user-supplied name
>   (when authenticating a server). A pattern may also be preceded by `!`
>   to indicate negation: if the host name matches a negated pattern, it
>   is not accepted (by that line) even if it matched another pattern on
>   the line. A hostname or address may optionally be enclosed within `[`
>   and `]` brackets then followed by ‘:’ and a non-standard port number.

It is possible to make a key trusted for

- a network range, if known, e.g. for `TEST-NET-2`:

  ```
  198.51.100.* ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...2iQ==
  ```
- multiple ranges (e.g. all `TEST-NET`s) using comma-separated list:

  ```
  192.0.2.*,198.51.100.*,203.0.113.* ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...2iQ==
  ```
- or even when connecting anywhere:

  ```
  * ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...2iQ==
  ```

If this key is not present, it will still warn you about the authenticity of the other keys, show the fingerprint and add it automatically, if you answer `yes`. The comparison is done line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Using the useful answer of Esa Jokinen and automatizing the process here my solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
previous_IP_OR_known_host_key_line=$1
current_IP=$2
user=$3
port=$4

#random extension to avoid collision by multiple script execution
temp_file="/tmp/temp_host_file.$(hexdump -n 2 -e '/2 "%u"' /dev/urandom)"

if [ "$(echo "$previous_IP_OR_known_host_key_line"|wc -w)" -gt 1 ]; then 
 echo "$previous_IP_OR_known_host_key_line"|sed "s/^[^ ]*/$current_IP/">"$temp_file"
else
 ssh-keygen -F "$previous_IP_OR_known_host_key_line"|grep -v "^#"|sed "s/^[^ ]*/$current_IP/">"$temp_file"
fi

ssh "$user"@"$current_IP" -p "$port" -o UserKnownHostsFile="$temp_file"

rm "$temp_file"
```

The script generates a temporary known_host file to provide to ssh.
The script needs of the following parameter (following the order):

-the destination IP that the machine had in previous accepted connections OR the corresponding RAW line with the key from known_host file.

-the current IP (behind the VPN/firewall).

-the user.

-the port.